# Component Libraries that Integrate with Theme-UI

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion, css-in-js, theme-ui

[Theme-UI](https://theme-ui.com/) has a number of [built-in compoments](https://theme-ui.com/components).  But they are all 'simple' components.  That is to say, no tabs, accordions, sortable tables or other components that have more 'sophisticated' functionality.

I am looking for suggestions for other component libraries that have that functionality, but which can sync well with theme-ui.  That is to say, I want to use the [theme](https://theme-ui.com/theming/) and [sx prop](https://theme-ui.com/sx-prop) of theme-ui, but with the functionality of another component library.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Theme-UI is intentionally unopinionated from a component point of view. Using it with Gatsby + MDX appears to be its mode.

If you haven't decided on a toolkit, these may be worth evaluating:

1. Grommet https://v2.grommet.io/
2. Chakra UI https://chakra-ui.com/
3. Welcome UI http://welcome-ui.com/

They all similarly use the style/theme props in using the same standard you see in theme-ui's `sx` prop.

And in my beginning research I found this article by Dotan Nahum really helpful: 
https://medium.com/@jondot/4-new-theme-based-react-ui-toolkits-and-why-its-going-to-change-how-you-think-72d276b1f6de.

Happy coding!